# ctrl + r not picking up the latest commands in history

Tags: bash, bash-history

when I enterl ctrl + r and enter a search term it goes back in distant history and never finds the commands that I most recently typed that has this keyword

Comment: Take a scrrenshot and post it.

Comment: what key-word? Those aren't Keywords.

Answer (score 0):

To check history of bash you need to type `history`, if you want to check only certain no.of your previous commands then type `history n`, where 'n' being no.of commands.

bash and bash-history aren't commands to store it in history,try some other keywords which aren't related to bash. If you check that history list, it is clear from that it doesn't store non-responsive and wrong commands.